# How to enable php-gmp on Mac OS X 10.6.6? (no macports)

Tags: php, macos, gmp, homebrew

I want to enable my php-gmp and I don't want to use macports because I use homebrew.

First I

> brew install gmp

and I got gmp 5.0.1

Then I downloaded the PHP source 5.3.6, then I go to

> source/ext/gmp

I did

> phpize

and then

> MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
>   CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386
>   -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure
>   --with-php-config=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/bin/php-config;
>   make -j6;sudo make install

And it gave me this message:

> checking for GNU MP support... yes,
>   shared checking for
>   __gmp_randinit_lc_2exp_size in -lgmp... no checking for gmp_randinit_lc_2exp_size in -lgmp...
>   no configure: error: GNU MP Library
>   version 4.1.2 or greater required.
>   make: *** No targets specified and no
>   makefile found.  Stop.

Any idea how to enable php-gmp without macports on Mac OSX 10.6.6? Thx

Answer (score 5):

If you have the [`homebrew-php` tap installed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php#installation), you can now do:

```
$ brew install php55 --with-gmp
```

Comment: Error: No available formula for php55

Comment: I've done `brew install php56 --with-gmp --with-fpm --with-homebrew-curl --with-homebrew-openssl` but I see in `php -i` output: `--without-gmp`. Really makes me sad after waiting for compilation of all this stuff :(
I've had to run `brew install php56-gmp` to install GMP module separately.

Answer (score 1):

Php-gmp is incompatible with GMP 5.0.1. This is a known bug, reported on [bugs.php.net](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50990) over a year ago. Check the comments on the bug to see if there's a workaround that works for you. If not, and if homebrew doesn't have a GMP 4.x package you can install instead, I think you're stuck building a copy of GMP 4.x manually. :-(

Comment: Thx I already downloaded and built gmp 4.3.2, Im trying to recompile php with gmp...dunno how.