# How to install php-gmp on OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, gmp

So I am trying to use php-gmp methods on my mac, but I get the error "`Call to undefined function gmp_init()`".

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576518/how-to-enable-php-gmp-on-mac-os-x-10-6-6-no-macports) answer that is basically the same question, but the question/answer are outdated - for example, the suggested brew package is not an available formula at this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install php56-gmp
```

Worked for me on php 5.6

`php -i | grep gmp` - to confirm

Don't forget to restart your webserver.