# How to enable GMP in PHP on OS X?

Tags: php, macos, gmp, osx-elcapitan

Using OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan) and PHP 5.5.29.

I would like to add the GMP extension to my PHP, but I have no clue to do so. According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php) I'm supposed compile PHP with a `--with-gmp=dir` option. But I don't know how to compile PHP (I doubt if I ever did it on this machine, iirc it just came with PHP by default), and I don't know what dir to use with that `--with-gmp=` option either.

I do have Homebrew, and I noticed a rather old [old similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576518/how-to-enable-php-gmp-on-mac-os-x-10-6-6-no-macports) however that doesn't seem to work (package no longer available).

I noticed in brew there is something called `homebrew/php/php55-gmp` but that suggests to something with `brew tap`. I have no clue what that is, and I'd rather not mess up my Homebrew config or my entire development environment (I guess that's unlikely, but I have no idea what I'm doing to my system when I mess with this tap stuff).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RocketNuts, you can simply execute:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php55-gmp
```

That's all what I did.

Comment: [Commonly](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1946), if you have upgraded either Xcode or the Mac OS since you installed PHP, you will have to also run `xcode-select --install` from the command line.

Comment: For PHP7, use `brew install homebrew/php/php70-gmp`

Comment: it necessary to reinstall php@7.1 with homebrew/core since homebrew/php is deprecated

Comment: @iMezied how do you do that with gmp? brew search gmp shows no php options, similiarly brew search php shows no gmp options.